# Python for loop with ifs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

## What I have:

I have two keys in a dictionary:

- one with values and
- one with the index of the value.

  ```
  d = {}
  d['inds'] = [0, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1]
  d['vals'] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
  ```

## What I want to do:

I want to loop through the dictionary and:

- If the next iteration index = the last iteration index +1, to list the corresponding value
- If the next iteration index does not = the last iteration index +1, print 0 and keep going. so basically just filling in 0 when there is a missing index

---

## What I have tried

**If I use the below loop:**

```
for i in d['inds']:
    for v in d['vals']:
        for x in range(0, i):
         if i == x+1:
             print(v)
             break
    else:
         print(0)
```

I get the list of values 6 times.

**So I tried swapping i and x:**

```
for i in d['inds']:
    for v in d['vals']:
        for x in range(0, i):
         if x == i+1:
             print(v)
             break
    else:
         print(0)
```

Now I just get 0 listed 7 times.

## TL;DR

How do I loop through a dictionary's values and indexes with a conditional statement, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see only one dictionary, `d`. What is the other one?

Comment: DYZ is right, you have two "keys" in your dictionary, but you are only showing a single dictionary.

Comment: sorry, yes, just one dictionary but two keys!

Comment: Can you try asking your question again? I cannot understand what you are trying to do yet.

Comment: there are two keys. hoping to create a vector from the keys, filling in values of zeros when the next numeric index is missing. hoping to get the end result of 1.0, 7.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 6.0 because 0's value was 1, 1's value was 7, 2s values were 4 and 5, 3 was missing so 0, 4s value was 3, 5s values were 2 and 6

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
for i in range(len(d['inds'])):
    if i in d['inds']:
        print(d['vals'][i])
    else:
        print(0)
```

This iterates through all the possible indices, prints 0 if the current index is not in d['inds'], and prints the value at the current index if it is.

Comment: kind of. definitely closer than what I had.
but hoping the end result would be:
1.0, 7.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 6.0

because 0's value was 1, 1's value was 7, 2s values were 4 and 5, 3 was missing so 0, 4s value was 3, 5s values were 2 and 6

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires functions `chain` and `defaultdict`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
```

Create a new dictionary of lists:

```
G = defaultdict(list)
```

Populate it with the data from `d`:

```
for k,v in zip(d['inds'], d['vals']):
    G[k].append(v)
#{0: [1.0], 5: [2.0, 6.0], 4: [3.0], 2: [4.0, 5.0], 1: [7.0]}
```

Create a range of indexes:

```
indexes = range(min(d['inds']), max(d['inds']) + 1)
```

Lookup each index in the new dictionary. If an index is not in the dictionary, use `[0]` as the value. The result is a nested list that can be flattened with `chain`:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(G.get(x, [0]) for x in indexes))
#[1.0, 7.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0, 3.0, 2.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: so is the get(x,[0]) getting the value from index x and putting zero when it doesn't find an x?

Comment: Correct.  It could bee replaced with `d[x] if x in d else []`.